# C++ unable to return a vector template

Tags: c++, list, templates, vector

I am trying to write a function that will convert a generic list to a vector, however, I cannot get my function to compile.  Here is my code (which sits in a .h file):

```
template <class T>
inline std::vector<T> list2vector(std::list<T> &l)
{
  std::vector<T> v;
  v.insert(v.begin(),l.begin(),l.end());
  return v;
}
```

Can anybody point out what I am missing here?
The compiler error is the following:

```
find_rpeat.cpp:85: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type
?std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&?
from a temporary of type
?std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >?
```

Comment: Maybe you need `const std::list<T>` in function signature?

Comment: This code compiled for me [http://ideone.com/p3CEt](http://ideone.com/p3CEt)

Comment: wow, adding the const did the trick, can you explain why that works?

Comment: Using GCC 4.6 (-Wall) this compiles without a single warning.

Comment: Could you post code that calls the function and fails to compile?

Comment: must be something compiler specific then, i'm using gcc version 4.1.2 and i need the const to get it to compile

Comment: Note there is a `vector` constructor that takes a range: `std::vector<T>(l.begin(), l.end());`

Comment: @user788171: are you calling this function like this: `list2Vector<int>(std::list<int>());`?

Comment: no, calling it like this: vector<string> myvector = list2vector(mylist);  where mylist is list<string> mylist;

Comment: @user788171: can you post the calling function? looks like `mylist` is a `const std::list<string>&` or the function you are trying to call this from is a `const` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<T> v;
std::copy(l.begin(),l.end(), std::back_inserter(v));
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments your code is something like that and it should compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
inline std::vector<T> list2vector(std::list<T> &l)
{
  std::vector<T> v;
  v.insert(v.begin(),l.begin(),l.end());
  return v;
}

int main() {
   list<string> mylist;
   vector<string> myvector = list2vector(mylist); 
   return 0;
}
```

But in order to produce your error message there should be something like: `vector<string>& myvector = list2vector(mylist);` (assign a temporary object to a non-const reference)

Answer (score 0):

There is already generic transform function for you in STL. Try

`std::transform(l.begin(), l.end(), std::back_inserter(v), Fn);`

I don't see any reason to write list2vector or something else if you can do that using STL. Think about it like mapping between two "generic" sets. In your case between list and vector.

Answer (score 0):

I seem you can create and fill vector in one line

```
std::vector<T> v (l.begin(), l.end());
```

And in C++11 it can be done even shorter

```
template <class T>
inline std::vector<T> list2vector(std::list<T> &l)
{
  return {l.begin(), l.end()};
}
```